# Variance estimation for Levy process

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, estimation, scale-invariance, levy-distribution

Let $(X_t)$ be a Levy process. It then holds that
$$
  E(X_{t+\Delta} - X_t) = \Delta \nu, \\
  V(X_{t+\Delta} - X_t) = \Delta \mu,
$$
under sufficient regularity conditions in terms of moments. For completeness, to see this, we may e.g. let $f(t) = EX_t$ and $g(t) = VX_t$, and obtain
$$
  f(s+t) = EX_{s+t} = E(X_{s+t} - X_t) + EX_t = f(s) + f(t)
$$
as well as
$$
  g(s+t) = VX_{s+t} = V((X_{s+t} - X_t) + X_t)\\ = V(X_{s+t} - X_t) + VX_t = g(s) + g(t),
$$
so $f$ and $g$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation, and therefore, under sufficient regularity conditions, is given by $f(t) = t\nu$ and $g(t) = t\mu$ for some $\nu$ and $\mu$.

**The question.** Assume that I observe $X_{t_0},\ldots,X_{t_n}$ for $0=t_0<\cdots<t_n$. What is a good (simple?) way to estimate $\mu$? And given such a sequence of estimators of $\mu$, how to I prove consistency as $n\to\infty$?

**A few thoughts.** Consider instead the problem of estimating $\nu$. Here, we know that $(t_i-t_{i-1})^{-1}(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})$ all have mean $\nu$ and are independent. Therefore, an appropriate version of the law of large numbers yields the result under sufficient regularity, e.g. using that for uncorrelated variables bounded in $L^2$ with the same mean, the empirical average converges to the mean. However, I'm not sure how to apply the same kind of trick for $\mu$.

Two main observations as regards solving the problem would most likely be the following. Defining
$$
Y_i = (t_i-t_{i-1})^{-1}(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}}), \\
Z_i = (t_i-t_{i-1})^{-1/2}(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}}),
$$
it holds that all $Y_i$ are independent and have the same mean, and all $Z_i$ are independent and have the same variance.